# How does Mule handle XML configuration that doesn't comply with its XML schema?

Tags: java, spring, mule

I've been assigned to work on a legacy system using Mule 2 and I've found some quirks in some of the old configuration. The developers who originally wrote the documentation has changed jobs so nobody has dared to change anything since.

```
<service name="taskCompleted">
        <inbound>
            <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="namespace.transporttask.completed">
                <jms:jmsmessage-to-object-transformer />

                <!-- This section does not comply with Mule's XML schema 
                     (Element message-properties-transformer is not allowed here) -->
                <message-properties-transformer>
                    <add-message-property key="MULE_ENCODING" value="windows-1252" />
                </message-properties-transformer>
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        </inbound>
        <bridge-component />
        <outbound>
            ...
        </outbound>
    </service>
```

This is just one of the examples I've found and my assumption is that Mule just ignores configuration like this and that it's safe to remove it as it probably doesn't do anything. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Is it not feasible to test the thing with confidence with that line removed?

Comment: It certainly is, but I'm curious about Mule's general handling of apparently invalid configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while IntelliJ IDEA has the best in class XML-schema-based editing for IDEs, it's not ideal still. As a rule of thumb, Mule will do full validation when parsing the config. The IDE may falsely flag valid config as errors, though.

And, Mule 2.x is quite old, what David has mentioned above applies to Mule 3 more. There were major schema improvements since Mule 2.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with IDEA. I see that they've had issues like this in the past. Upgrading to Mule 3 would be nice, but I don't see that happening with this legacy system.

Answer (score 3):

Mule strictly validates the configuration it loads: if elements are misplaced or not allowed at all, Mule will not load the configuration and refuse to start this application.

If Mule starts fine with this configuration, it means it's valid and the comment is lying.

Comment: Okay, so it's actually a problem with Mule's XML schema?

Comment: Or with the tool that is using Mule's complex hierarchies of schemas to validate the XML. Are we talking about an XML editor here?

Comment: That's also an option. I'm using Intellij Idea 11.